# Swf Upload System IO error - Progress bar getting stuck

Tags: swfupload

After reading Steve Sandersons post on swf upload.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

I have implemented the swf upload on a site I am working on, Some users are getting a variety of issues where the progress bar gets stuck, or they get the error message 2038 - with error code -220 (System IO error.) - this is not related to Certificates as in the test below both addresses can be accessed with http or https

I haven't been able to reproduce much of these errors, However when trying to upload large images over 2 mb

It works fine on the test site, But not on the live

UPDATE: I had posted examples here, now removed as the links don't work.

Both sites hosted on App Harbor. exactly the same code.

The Limit for image uploads should be 10 mb - and I have successfully uploaded larger images that the one posted here.

what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Update, - I've turned on debug info on the [site](http://spacehive.com/test/swfupload) on larger file sizes 4mb + the upload just stops, no error message. bar gets suck

Comment: Update 2 - most people now getting error message Upload error
Code: -200
Message: 413
The upload will now be cancelled, please try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a configurations setting at the load balancer level, We have a dedicated load balancer with app harbor to so we can offer full ssl support. It had not been set up to allow requestes of 10mb, they have changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask what language the rest of the site is written in?

My first thought is that if it's an IO error it could be running out of space?

Run:

```
Df -h
```

On the servers and see what we get, remember that all file uploads are written to /tmp before being moved where you want them, so if that fills upload stops.

Comment: Written in asp.net c#, images hosted on amazon s3. I don't have admin access to the server, as its hosted on appharbor. but when I change the config values to run this code locally, it works fine.

Comment: Last time I saw one of those errors was when my host had set /tmp to be memcached and as such the size was about 500mb, so whenever I had a load of files in there (things weren't cleaning down) it would bomb with an IO error. To fix I asked the host to revert /tmp to a normal dir.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't forget to have the parameters in php.ini that set :

```
session cookies to on
and session.use_only_cookies to off
```

and in the js plugin session are handled this way:

```
 post_params: {
   <?php echo "'".ini_get('session.name')."':'".session_id()."',"; ?>
 }
```

Furthermore, don't forget to check the list of images extensions handled by your js plugin